# Taking attribute from multiple points within a set distance

Tags: geospatial

QGIS Question: I have a list of point features each with a unique ID. I need to run a fixed distance buffer on all 70,000 points to establish which points are within a fixed distance of each other than return the unique IDs for each point. These need to be within columns in the attributes table.

So point 1 (id-A) might have point 9 (id-x) and Point 87 (id-c) within 1 km. I need the attributes table of point 1 to list id-A, then id-x then id c, all in columns for export to excel where I can concentrate them with comers in between.

Comment: I think this is really more of a GIS question, since you appear to be asking about transforming existing data, not obtaining new data.

Comment: I agree with @BarryCarter on this one. Have you tried asking this question over at https://gis.stackexchange.com/ yet?

Comment: Create a buffer, then either `join attributes by location` or `join attributes by location(summary)`. If you post this on GIS stackexchange I can answer with more details.